# How to check if column is empty or blank ('') for all present rows?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with 100+ free fields. I want to make a script that checks if a column is either null or empty for all rows present.

How would I do this? I would like to make it dynamic afterwards so it can do it for every column and insert the columname in a temp table to show which ones are useable.

Comment: `where the_column is null or the_column = ''`?

Answer (score 1):

If I got this right, you want to check if *all* rows are null or empty in a given column. It should not report a column, where there are only *some* null or empty fields?

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` for that. Check if no rows exist, where the column is *not* empty not null.

```
SELECT '<column_name>' column_name
       WHERE NOT EXITS (SELECT *
                               FROM elbat
                               WHERE isnull(<column_name>, '') <> '');
```

If you want to count columns, that only consist of white spaces too, use [`rtrim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in addition to strip white spaces prior checking for equality to the empty string.

```
SELECT '<column_name>' column_name
       WHERE NOT EXITS (SELECT *
                               FROM elbat
                               WHERE rtrim(isnull(<column_name>, '')) <> '');
```

Replace `<column_name>` with you actual column name.

To reuse it for several column names, you'd have to use dynamic SQL. Build the query as a `nvarchar` inserting the desired column name in the right spots and execute it with [`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You can get the column names of your table from the catalog.

```
SELECT c.name
       FROM sys.columns c
            INNER JOIN sys.tables t
                       ON t.object_id = c.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
                       ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
       WHERE s.name = '<schema_name>'
             AND t.name = '<table_name>';
```

Replace `<schema_name>` with your schema name and `<table_name>` with your table name.

Use a [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to loop over the results from the catalog.